# How to stop the cyclic trigger when inserting a record?

Tags: trigger

I write trigger on account, when i insert account record then contact inserted. I write another trigger on contact object, when i insert contact record then account also inserted. In this case two triggers fired cyclic. so, How to stop in this case. Can anybody explain on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger framework, or, if this sounds too advanced, just create a static class with a Boolean attribute and call it `accountTriggerRun`, for example. When the account trigger is run, set it to true. On the same trigger, check if this attribute is true or false, if it is true, then don't execute the trigger's code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Class checkRecursive 
{
    private static boolean run = true;
    public static boolean runOnce() 
    {
        if (run) 
        {
            run = false;
            return true;
        } else 
        {
            return run;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: N.B. Using a static boolean to control trigger recursion means that `runOnce()` will only return true once. If you are working with more than 200 records, or use this specific recursion control mechanism in other places as well, it's quite likely that you'll end up preventing code from being run when you truly do want it to be run. The minimum I'd recommend for recursion control is a `Set<Id>` (hold and check to see if this record Id has been seen before), with the next step being using a `Map<String, Set<Id>>` (more granular control, can be used in multiple methods or classes).